# abstract classes in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to create an abstract class in C#. Currently, I have this class in C#:

```
public class CreditReportViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }       
    public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
    public string PersonalAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmployerAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make it abstract class and two other classes will inherit it. Do I just need to place abstract keyword with class to need to change properties as well. What about classes which will inherit this class. What need to be changed in these classes?

Please suggest.

Comment: I have to admit I'd suggest just trying to put the abstract keyword in and seeing what happens when you compile. :)

Comment: If this is all the behaviour in CreditReportViewModel, it might make more sense as an Interface, although in that case implementors will actually have to do some implementing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing needed to make the class `abstract` is to add the keyword:

```
public abstract class CreditReportViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }       
    public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
    public string PersonalAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmployerAddress { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, implementing classes do not need to add any additional implementation:

```
class Derived : CreditReportViewModel { }
```

If you want to make members `abstract` as well, same thing goes there:

```
public abstract class CreditReportViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }       
    public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
    public string PersonalAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmployerAddress { get; set; }
    public abstract float MakeSomeCalculation();
}

public class Derived : CreditReportViewModel
{
    public override float MakeSomeCalculation()
    {
         // This method must be implemented in the derived class
    }
}
```

The typical case is that the `abstract` base class exposes some `abstract` members that need to be implemented by derived classes.

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is mark the class as `abstract`:

```
public abstract class CreditReportViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }       
    public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
    public string PersonalAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmployerAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you want the class to be. Usually it is enough to place the abstract keyword on the class level. If you want to have abstract properties, you have to mark them abstract as well.

Derived classes don't need any change as long as you mark the only the class as abstract. With abstract properties you force the derived classes to implement these properties.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to place abstract keyword like

```
public abstract class CreditReportViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }       
    public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
    public string PersonalAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmployerAddress { get; set; }
}
```

but I don't think any **valid reason** you should make the above class abstract.